# Pandas Vectorized Profitable Close

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I am trying to find a speedy implementation where I can determine a way to find exit points given N profitable closes after initial trigger signal.

So to clearly define a profitable close, imagine we are just got a long signal telling us to buy now at price 100. The exit strategy is such that we will close our existing long position if there is N=2 closes (doesn't have to be sequential) where the price is greater than our entry price of 100.

```
signal = pd.DataFrame([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], columns=["signal"])
price = pd.DataFrame([100,99,100,99,98,101,99,99,98,90,102,90,103,20,110,120,130], columns=["price"])
data = pd.concat([signal,price],axis=1)
```

So in the above I am some sample data. The Correct answer is exit on the row index `10`.

The way I am (incorrectly) doing it now is :

```
long_short = 1 # 1 equal going only only, -1 is going short
profit_n_exit = 2
sig_diffed = signal .diff().fillna(0.0).replace(-long_short,0)
sig_entry_px = (sig_diffed.replace(0,np.nan) * price ).fillna(method='pad')

# Profitable Closes Given Direction
exit_sig1 = ((np.sign(price  - sig_entry_px).fillna(0) == long_short) * 1)#.replace(0,np.nan)


# Cumulative Count of Profitable Closes
profit_close = (exit_sig1.groupby((exit_sig1 != exit_sig1.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1) * exit_sig1
profit_close = SignalFill(sig_diffed, sig_diffed.shift(profit_n_exit - 1)).replace(1,np.nan).replace(0,1) * profit_close
profit_close = ((profit_close >= profit_n_exit) * 1)
```

My implementation only seems to count sequential profitable consecutive closes. I need to find a way to also count non-sequential profitable closes too. any ideas?

Comment: is there exactly one 1 on `signal`?

Comment: oh no, there can be more. the above example is just when there is only 1 signal.

Comment: So if there are two signals, you want 2 closes? And what if a signal does not have a 2nd close?

Comment: ya thats correct

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that gives the *values* of the wanted closes, and return 0 if there are less than 2 closes for a signal:

```
def get_second(x):
    tmp = x[x.gt(x.iloc[0])]
    return 0 if len(tmp) < 2 else tmp.iloc[1]

data.groupby(data.signal.cumsum()).price.apply(get_second)
```

Output:

```
signal
0      0
1    102
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

If we want the *index* (row number) of the close:

```
def get_second_index(x):
    tmp = x[x.gt(x.iloc[0])]
    return -1 if len(tmp) < 2 else tmp.index[1]

(data.groupby(data.signal.cumsum())
     .price.apply(get_second_index))
```

gives

```
signal
0    -1
1    10
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Another test case:

```
signal = pd.DataFrame([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1], columns=["signal"])
price = pd.DataFrame([100,99,100,99,98,101,99,99,98,90,102,90,103,20,110,120,130], columns=["price"])
data = pd.concat([signal,price],axis=1)
data
```

gives:

```
signal
0      0
1    102
2    120
3      0
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

and

```
signal
0    -1
1    10
2    15
3    -1
Name: price, dtype: int64
```